# Ping Sequence Numbers Synchronize on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, network-programming, ping, icmp

I've noticed that over a long-duration two-2ay ping between two windows machines, the sequence numbers embedded in the pings ICMP packets synchronize. Is this expected and, if so, does anybody know why this is done?

Comment: What do you mean by this ? Perhaps show us an example.

Comment: Host a is pinging host b, and simultaneously, host b is pinging host a. Using Wireshark, I see that the a-to-b and b-to-a ping packets start out with different sequence numbers. However, over time, these sequence numbers converge. This is occurring on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this expected

No. Just a fluke, or a consequence of how the sequence numbers are constructed.

> and, if so, does anybody know why this is done?

It isn't done at all. The ping at one end doesn't know what sequence numbers a ping at the other end is using. It doesn't even see them.